# iterm2 - vim is printing line numbers while scrolling

Tags: linux, vim, mouse, editors, iterm2

In iterm2, while scrolling in the vim I see a strange behavior. Whenever I am scrolling it is printing line number with scrolling. How to overcome from this behavior

```
call-hometic_scale_1.txt" 3248L, 118730C                                45,1          Top
                                                                        46,1           0%
contact smart-licensing                                                 47,1           0%
profile ZnscoTAC-1                                                      48,1           0%
active                                                                  49,1           0%
destination transport-method http                                       50,1           0%
!                                                                       51,1           0%
!                                                                       52,1           0%
hw-module profile npu native-mode-enable                                53,1           0%
```

Comment: Your question needs to show answerers the result of `:set term` in VIM, tell answerers what the terminal (emulator) that you are using is, and explain exactly how you are performing this scrolling, with what human input device and with what input.

Answer (score 1):

You have the number of rows in your terminal window (iterm2) set to be one less than the number of rows that your OS and editor expect. For example, you have iterm2 set to 24 rows but `stty -a` reports 25 rows.

Fix one or the other